# Specifying application version in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, versioning, resource-files

At our shop, our applications need to specify the application version.
The version components are Major.Minor.Build-Number.

Long time ago, in a past version of Visual Studio, there was a project file that specified the version number.  What is the project file / solution file that I need to modify to set the application version in VS2019?

Further back in time, I remember setting the version in a resource file.
What are the statements / keywords to set the application version in VS2019?

Note:  the application version number (string) is shown, in Windows 10, in the properties of the application.

**Edit 1:** More details.
The application is a console application running on Windows 10, the allows modifying of data files for testing of a product.  No GUI, no MFC, no Qt, no wxWidgets; just a program using old fashioned console I/O and file I/O.  The program is run in a command line window.

Comment: There is a similar field, "ProductVersion", in the Installer project file, *.vdproj.

Comment: As far as I know, if you create a C++ Windows application (MFC) with the wizard, you get a ressource file (.RC). If you should the ressource tab, you can edit it the designer. Once you know how it works, you can also add one to an existing project. As far as I now, there is no automatic numbering available in C++.

Comment: What project are you using? Win32, MFC,  qt?

Comment: You need a resource file with a `VERSIONINFO` resource in it; that will have fields, `FILEVERSION` and `PRODUCTVERSION`, which have values of the form, `1,2,3,4`, which will show as `1.2.3.4` in the "details" page of the executable file's properties. [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource)

Comment: You can also define a version number in a header file, like `#define PROGVER 1,2,3,4` and, if that header is `#include`d in the `.rc` (or `.rc2`) file, you can use that macro/token as your `PRODUCTVERSION` value, so you'll only ever have to change the v ersion in the header.

Comment: Hard to give a 'proper' answer without knowing a bit more about how your project is structured...

Comment: The project is a console application for Windows 10, to be more specific, it helps prepare data for the testing of a product.  No GUI.  Just console I/O and file I/O.

Comment: Project > Add Resource > Version

Comment: Add a resource file (.rc) to your project, then use the resource editor, Add Resource, Version.